# How to add some prefab JavaScript into a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wish to add an updating clock to a page created with React. [Here is](https://codepen.io/jasonleewilson/pen/gPrxwX) the original CodePen demo. I am unsure how to integrate the JavaScript that drives the clock. I am using FunctionalComponents. Where do I put the JavaScript code?

My existing app *(with the added clock HTML in `.clockDiv`)*:

```
import { h, FunctionalComponent } from 'preact';
import style from './company.scss';
import Markup from 'preact-markup';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'preact/hooks';
import { get } from '../../utils/ajax';
import { SvgMap } from './Components/SvgMap';
import { AppContext, CMSContent } from '../../store/store';

export const Company: FunctionalComponent = () => {
  const { language: lang } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [pageContent, setpageContent] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  /* *********************************************************************** */
  useEffect(() => {
    const companyTab = 'Company';
    const editCompany = 'locUSA';
    get<CMSContent[]>(`/getPageHTML?tab=${companyTab}&company=${editCompany}&lang=${lang}`).then((companyContent) => {
      setpageContent(companyContent[0].html);
    });
  }, [lang]);
  /* *********************************************************************** */

  return (
    <div class={style.companyDiv}>
      <div class={style.pageData}>
        {pageContent !== undefined && (
          <Typography>
            <div class={style.topStuff}>
              <div class={style.pageContent}>
                <Markup markup={pageContent} trim={false} type='html' />
              </div>
              <div class={style.clockDiv}>
                <div class={style.timedate}>
                  <a id="mon">January</a>
                  <a id="d">1</a>,
                  <a id="y">0</a><br />
                  <a id="h">12</a> :
                  <a id="m">00</a>:
                  <a id="s">00</a>:
                  <a id="mi">000</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Company;
```

The JavaScript that drives the clock is:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(n) {
  for (let r = this.toString(); r.length < n; r = 0 + r);
  return r;
};

function updateClock() {
  const now = new Date();
  const milli = now.getMilliseconds();
  const sec = now.getSeconds();
  const min = now.getMinutes();
  const hou = now.getHours();
  const mo = now.getMonth();
  const dy = now.getDate();
  const yr = now.getFullYear();
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  const tags = ["mon", "d", "y", "h", "m", "s", "mi"];
  const corr = [months[mo], dy, yr, hou.pad(2), min.pad(2), sec.pad(2), milli];
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(tags[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = corr[i];
}

function initClock() {
  updateClock();
  window.setInterval("updateClock()", 1);
}
```

This is the first time I've looked at integrating a normal JavaScript widget into a React app. It's a very simple widget being added to a very simple page so it must be reasonably straight-forward to do, but TBH I'm not sure where to begin.

Is there a HowTo for this sort of thing?

PS - Preact is almost identical to React, any Reactic solutions will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the JS code as a separate file that exports the `updateClock` function or define it within your `Company` component file.

Then add another `useEffect` to call the `updateClock` function, to replace the original `initClock` function.

Something like this:

```
// Import or define the updateClock function...
import { updateClock } from './utils/clock';

// Within your component...
useEffect(() => {
  updateClock();
  const interval = window.setInterval(updateClock, 1);
  // Clear the interval if/when the component is removed from the DOM
  return () => window.clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

**NOTE:** Untested code, may need tweaks...

Of course this isn't really the react way to do this, but I don't have time to rewrite the function to be more reactive.